# Is it OK to reheat hash browns the next morning?

Tags: reheating

Hash browns are delicious and delectable, but I do not have time to cook them every morning. I was wondering if it was OK to cook hash browns tonight and them eat them cold or reheat them in the microwave for 10 seconds the next morning? Will I have to keep them in the fridge, or just covered for the night? These are the hash browns that I will be using:

[image: McCain Hash Browns]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Frozen hash browns like that are already pretty much cooked. When you bake them, you're really just heating them up and crisping the outside.

If you cook some then save them, they're going to lose a lot of that crispiness no matter what you do. If you eat them cold they'll be, well, cold. If you heat them in the microwave, they'll soften even more. If you still like them, go for it.

Safety-wise, it's fine. You do need to keep them in the fridge, as with pretty much any other leftover food.

Comment: Have you tried them in the toaster?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of microwaving them, maybe you would have enough time to throw them under the broiler on a cookie sheet lined with parchment paper.  It wouldn't take long and would be crispy and hot.

Comment: You'd probably want to microwave them some first. If they're refrigerated, they're going to brown on the outside before they heat through properly.

Comment: Given the size of the pictured hashbrowns - I disagree.

Comment: The size is hard to tell from the picture. What I do know is that they take, according to [the instructions](http://www.mccain.com.au/products_everythingpotato_mccain-potato-snacks_hash-browns-750g_143.aspx), 15-20 minutes in a preheated 230C/450F oven. If it takes that long to get them properly cooked with full heat all around, high heat from the top is unlikely to heat them all the way through in a few minutes, and it will overbrown them quickly if they're already cooked. (It also says 7 minutes with frequent turning under the broiler. Same point there.)

Answer (score 0):

I just reheated some leftover hash-browns in a skillet and they were great. They were from a restaurant, crispy on the outside but still soft on the inside. I broke them up and first warmed them in the microwave (good suggestion above) for 30 seconds. On high heat, with a little butter, I put the potatoes in the skillet and let them sit for a couple minutes then turned them with a spatula. I did this a few times then cracked two eggs on top, and put a lid on it for a couple of minutes until the yolks looked pink. Slid it on a plate, added S&P and dug in. Delish, fast and easy.